# PHP result as variable in text / element field (use php output in 'placeholder' field)

Tags: php, bitcoin

I am loading the current `bitcoin price` to my webpage using:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
     function()
     {$('.btc-price').load('gox.php');}, 10000);
```

I can get the current price to display with:

```
<div class="btc-price"></div>
```

But I want to use the price as a 'placeholder' in an input field:

```
<input placeholder="[current bitcoin price here]" />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what does gox.php return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide an `id` to your input field and then set the attribute `placeholder` through jquery.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
     function()
     {$.get('gox.php', function (data) {
          $("#inputid").attr('placeholder', data);
     });}, 10000);
```

Comment: +1 assuming gox.php returns only the value this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Thank you! Another question... how do I make the price load into the placeholder attribute instantly? Right now it waits 10 seconds before it updates. I'd like to load the value as soon as the page is loaded and then have the function you wrote refresh it every 10 seconds.

I tried removing the 'setinterval' and 10000 pieces but then it doesn't work.